Extrude tool, add gizmo for a along axis not just normal orientation?
How can I add gizmo to extrude function so I can extrude along the axis not normal?
The yellow plus is 'normals orientation' and white line freehand.


press E to extrude then press the axis you want twice?

I use on screen keyboard only and messes up when i do.

To extrude along axis - you should do two things :
1) Click on the XYZ icon in the top left corner :

2) Drag the gizmo's part which is colored same as the axis of your choice :

That's it  :-)

perfect tested and works ty, was just what was looking for. searched everywhere

@matteh, "perfect tested and works" — Up-vote (*as an addition to "accepted" tick) would be appreciated

Tried when did but don't have enough points sorry.
